How to get error message for submitBatch with OData V4 in SAPUI5
When creating new entities in SAPUI5 using submitBatch for a OData V4 service, messages can be read using getMessages() for the bound context. This will however not return any technical messages.
For instance, if I try to create an entity which is currently locked in the backend, the console will show message 'Uncaught (in promise) Error: You can't edit this instance at the moment. It's currently locked.' but this error is not returned by getMessages().
How can I get these type of messages?
This is the code I'm using to create entities.
let bindingContext = this.getView().getBindingContext()
let path = "/Contract('" + bindingContext.getObject().Contract + "')"

this.oContext = oModel.bindContext( path, null, {
    $$updateGroupId: "cmpchange"
})

this.oContext.getBoundContext().setProperty("Contract", this.Contract)

    oModel.submitBatch("cmpchange").then(function(oEvent){
        let messages = this.oContext.getBoundContext().getMessages()
        if (messages.length > 0) {
            let oJSONModel = new JSONModel()
            oJSONModel.setData(messages)
            this.oMessageView.setModel(oJSONModel)
            this.oMessageDialog.open()
        } 
    }.bind(this))


maybe  oModel.submitBatch("cmpchange").then()..catch(/* here*/). Your error states quite clear thats this is exception within the promise chain


The Promise you get from submitBatch
Throws an error if its not succesful.
You have to pass it a second function where you handle the error.
oModel.submitBatch("cmpchange").then(
    function (oEvent) {
        let messages = this.oContext.getBoundContext().getMessages();
        if (messages.length > 0) {
            let oJSONModel = new JSONModel();
            oJSONModel.setData(messages);
            this.oMessageView.setModel(oJSONModel);
            this.oMessageDialog.open();
        }
    },
    function (oError) {
        // here you get the error in oError
    }
)
.bind(this);

